# Forceclose error receiving

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the following function:

```
public Cursor DisplayAmericanStarterRecipe(String cat)
{
    return db.query(American_Recipes_Table, new String[] {
            Recipe_ID,Recipe_Type,Recipe_Category,Recipe_Title,Recipe_Time,Recipe},
            Recipe_Type+"="+cat,
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null);              
};
```

From MainActivity.java I am calling the above function like this:

```
DBAdapter m=new DBAdapter(MainActivity.this);
            m.open();
            Cursor id3 = m.DisplayAmericanStarterRecipe("Dessert");
            if (id3.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    DisplayparticularTitle(id3);
                } while (id3.moveToNext());
            }   
            m.close();
```

I am passing "Dessert" as argument to the first function so that the function can give back the selected records on the basis of "dessert" string but I am receiving FORCECLOSE error. Is this the correct way to pass string value or some other way is there?

Comment: Please look up the exact error in LogCat, as a force close can be anything. There it'll also give you the line in code causing the error. If you're still not comfortable after that with, edit your question and add the stack trace.

Comment: See logcat and find out exactly what caused the forceclose error. It will help you.

Comment: make sure your query is written right - debug the whole query in the SQLiteBrowser or some other DB management soft. And learn how to use logCat